# JPA native query with annotation executes different query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to implement an example like this: A Person class has a list of places that it likes. But when I want to query it, I want result as each person with only the most favorite place(just the first one not all of them). So I have done this:

```
@Entity
class Person{

    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "person_favorite_place",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "place_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    @OrderColumn(name="favorite_place_order")
    List<Place> favoritePlaces;
}
```

And in repository, I did:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select person0_.id as id1_0_0_, person0_.age as age2_0_0_, person0_.name as name3_0_0_, favoriteme1_.person_id as person_id1_1_1_, place2_.id as place_id2_1_1_, favoriteme1_.favorite_place_order as favorite3_1_, place2_.id as id1_3_2_, place2_.invented as invented2_3_2_, place2_.name as name3_3_2_ from person person0_ left outer join person_favorite_place favoriteme1_ on person0_.id=favoriteme1_.person_id left outer join place place2_ on favoriteme1_.place_id=place2_.id where person0_.id=:personId  and favoriteme1_.favorite_place_order = 0", nativeQuery = true)
    Person getPersonWithFavoritePlace(@Param("personId") Long personId);

}
```

But it seems , there are 2 sql queries is getting run. the first one is:

```
select person0_.id as id1_0_0_, person0_.age as age2_0_0_, person0_.name as name3_0_0_, favoriteme1_.person_id as person_id1_1_1_, place2_.id as place_id2_1_1_, favoriteme1_.favorite_place_order as favorite3_1_, place2_.id as id1_3_2_, place2_.invented as invented2_3_2_, place2_.name as name3_3_2_ from person person0_ left outer join person_favorite_place favoriteme1_ on person0_.id=favoriteme1_.person_id left outer join place place2_ on favoriteme1_.place_id=place2_.id where person0_.id=:personId  and favoriteme1_.favorite_place_order = 0
```

the second one:

```
select favoriteme0_.person_id as person_id1_1_0_, favoriteme0_.place_id as place_id2_1_0_, favoriteme0_.favorite_place_order as favorite3_0_, place1_.id as id1_3_1_, place1_.invented as invented2_3_1_, place1_.name as name3_3_1_ from person_favorite_place favoriteme0_ inner join place place1_ on favoriteme0_.place_id=place1_.id where favoriteme0_.person_id=?
```

I can understand the first one, which is completely the query that I want to execute but the second one , I do not know where it comes. So I think, because of that I am having all the favorite places of a person but not the most desired one.

Any ideas?

BR

PS: I have written the query over native output of "findOne" method. Just added "and favoriteme1_.favorite_place_order = 0" in the end. Also I have tried to use the exact query without modification and it worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

The second query is used to load the favoritePlaces that you defined with FetchType.EAGER

Comment: I now but the point is: when I replace my custom method with findOne(id), it runs only one sql query. Also favoritePlaces has already been fethed in my own query. So why does it executes another one?

Comment: If you execute findOne it will do a JOIN of these two tables. But when you create your own SQL it thinks that there are is not enough data to build the favoritePlaces. Is you SQL the same as the one from findOne?

Comment: in findOne(id) hibernate can construct a query with JOIN and can be sure that this query is correct and can map results to your collection. Buy with your query it can't be sure if all necessary columns were loaded. Also loading not full collection is a dangerous way, if anywhere then you will call save() on Person entity all other can be deleted.

Comment: yeah, I have actually built my sql from it. Just added "and favoriteme1_.favorite_place_order = 0" in the end

Answer (score 0):

Your repository is querying Persons but not places and because of FetchType.EAGER loads all Places also with the second query; To query for the Places use PlacesRepository.

Comment: yes but my query is also fetching all it needs. Why does the JPA try to fetch again? Also pleace check the comment that Ihave written Simon

Comment: Hibernate does not analyze your native query, it just understands that result should be Person and maps necessary fields to person. Any additional columns are ignored.

Comment: How come it does not execute the secondary when I call findOne(id) method?

Comment: I believe that it uses joins instead of a separate query. It can't rely on your native query join.